# Edit functions in bash - awk

Tags: bash

I have such a function...

```
 function size {

      export FILENAME=$1

      export SIZE=$(du -sb $FILENAME | awk '{ print $1 }')

      awk 'BEGIN{x = ENVIRON["SIZE"]
                 split("Byte KiloByte MegaByte GigaByte TeraByte PetaByte ExaByte ZettaByte YottaByte", type)
                 for(i=8; y < 1; i--)
                     y = x / (2**(10*i))
                     print y " " type[i+2]
      }'

 }
```

size "/home/foo.bar" # 1 MegaByte

how can I insert: **print y " " type[i+2]**

to variable: SIZE_FILE ?

test: SIZE_FILE=${print y " " type[i+2]} # error :-(

Thank you very much

Comment: `du -hs $FILENAME | awk '{print $1}'` would seem to be much easier.

Comment: Note that 1024 bytes is a kibibyte (KiB). A kilobyte (kB) is 1000 bytes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KiB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $( expr ) construct will save the result of evaluating "expr" in to a variable:

```
 theDate=$(date)
```

You can also use backticks, but I think the $() is more readable:

```
   theDate=`date`
```

So for your scripts, you'll use:

```
    function size {

          export FILENAME=$1

          SIZE=$(du -sb $FILENAME | awk '{ print $1 }')

          export FILE_SIZE=$(awk -v x=$SIZE 'BEGIN{
                     split("Byte KiloByte MegaByte GigaByte TeraByte PetaByte ExaByte ZettaByte YottaByte", type)
                     for(i=8; y < 1; i--)
                         y = x / (2**(10*i))
                         print y " " type[i+2]
          }')

    echo $FILE_SIZE

 }
```

Comment: Also, Do you really want to export all of the variables?

Comment: Thank you for your help. No, just a variable named $FILE_SIZE. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Instead of exporting the variable, just pass it into `awk` with the `-v` flag: `awk -v x=$SIZE '...'`. No need at all to export `FILENAME` or `FILE_SIZE`.

Comment: You don't need the "export" part unless you need those variables to be accesible to the caller.

Comment: @Dave: hope you don't mind, I edited your answer to demonstrate the `-v` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `awk`, which is more suited for processing text files.

```
function size () {

    # Non-environment variables should be lowercased
    # Always quote parameter expansions, in case they contain spaces
    local filename="$1"

    # Simpler way to get the file size in bytes
    local size=$(stat -c%s "$filename")

    # You could put all the units in an array, but we'll keep it simple.
    for unit in Byte KiloByte MegaByte GigaByte TeraByte PetaByte ExaByte ZettaByte YottaByte; do
        echo "$size $unit"
        (( size /= 1024 ))
    done

}

sizes=$( size $myfile )
```